# Не может создать Bean

Tags: java, spring

При попытке связать с бином

```
@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
```

в контроллере,  выдает ошибку

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'logonController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
private springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService
springtest.web.LogonController.myUserDetailsService; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

сам класс

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

//get user from the database, via Hibernate
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    kz.tanikin.springtest.domain.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}

@Transactional
public void addUser(kz.tanikin.springtest.domain.User user){
    userDao.addUser(user);
}


private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
    return Result;
}


}
```

в data.xml написано

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService" />
```

Этот класс используется для авторизации springSecurity.

В чем может быть дело? Нужно делать записи в БД при регистрации пользователей?

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="springtest.**"/>` не забыли указать в контексте?

Comment: да прописано     <context:component-scan base-package="springtest.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="springtest.service" />

Comment: Попробуйте оставить только один component-scan для пакета `springtest`

Comment: Пробовал, такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте для `MyUserDetailsService` добавить аннотацию `@Configurable`

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Configurable
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService { ... }
```

И еще. Аннотация @Service("userDetailsService") поднимает бин "userDetailsService". xml-конфиг должен (но в нашем случае не поднял) бин "myUserDetailsService", который и должен был быть проинициализирован через Autowired

Если не принципиально делать из класса "MyUserDetailsService" два разных бина, то предлагаю:
1. Из data.xml убрать инициализацию.
2. Аннотацию @Service("userDetailsService") сократить до просто @Service. Тогда аннотация сделает сервис-бин с именем по классу, т.е. myUserDetailsService

Еще можно сделать

```
@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

Тогда будет подниматься бин по имени из аннотации @Service("userDetailsService")
Но и в этом случае data.xml не нужен

Почему не поднялся бин из data.xml надо смотреть более широкий лог с начала запуска. Какие бины, откуда и  в каком порядке поднимаются.

Comment: Добавил, ошибка такая же.

Comment: Если уберу из data.xml в security.xml не может найти этот бин,     <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
    </authentication-manager>
пробовал указывать @Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
такая же ошибка